# Animation using ObjectAnimator causes keyboard to overlap EditText

Tags: android, animation, android-softkeyboard, android-constraintlayout, objectanimator

The EditText is not blocked by the keyboard before animations, however once the edit text is translated using ObjectAnimator, keyboard overlaps.

Here are the animation:

```
ObjectAnimator emailFieldTranslation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(emailField,"TranslationY", -200f);
        emailFieldTranslation.setDuration(400);
        ObjectAnimator passwordFieldTranslation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(passwordField,"TranslationY", -200f);
        passwordFieldTranslation.setDuration(400);
        ObjectAnimator repeatPasswordFieldTranslation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(repeatPasswordField,"TranslationY", -200f);
        repeatPasswordFieldTranslation.setDuration(400);
        ObjectAnimator signInButtonTranslation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(emailSignInButton,"TranslationY", -200f);
        signInButtonTranslation.setDuration(400);
        ObjectAnimator signInButtonDownTranslation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(emailSignInButton,"TranslationY", 100f);
        signInButtonDownTranslation.setDuration(400);
        ObjectAnimator repeatFieldFadeInAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(repeatPasswordField, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
        repeatFieldFadeInAnimation.setDuration(400);
        ObjectAnimator repeatFieldScaleXAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(repeatPasswordField,"ScaleX",0f,1f);
        repeatFieldScaleXAnimation.setDuration(400);
        ObjectAnimator repeatFieldScaleYAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(repeatPasswordField,"ScaleY",0f,1f);
        repeatFieldScaleYAnimation.setDuration(400);

        AnimatorSet repeatPasswordIn = new AnimatorSet();
        repeatPasswordIn.playTogether(repeatFieldScaleXAnimation,repeatFieldScaleYAnimation,repeatFieldFadeInAnimation,signInButtonDownTranslation);
        repeatPasswordIn.setDuration(400);
        repeatPasswordIn.start();

        AnimatorSet translateFieldsUp = new AnimatorSet();
        translateFieldsUp.playTogether(emailFieldTranslation,passwordFieldTranslation,repeatPasswordFieldTranslation,signInButtonTranslation);
        translateFieldsUp.setDuration(400);
        translateFieldsUp.start();

        SpringAnimation anim =
            new SpringAnimation(logo, DynamicAnimation.TRANSLATION_Y, -150f);
        anim.getSpring().setDampingRatio(DAMPING_RATIO_MEDIUM_BOUNCY);
        anim.getSpring().setStiffness(STIFFNESS_LOW);
        anim.start();
```

[image]

Comment: can you post images of what is happening ? thanks

Comment: Image is updated

Comment: Please add your xml! plus, now with constraintlayout there is a better way to handle animations using constraintset and transitionmanager.

Comment: I just got it working.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <activity
        android:name=".view.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">
```

I just added adjustResize to the windowSoftInputMode and I got it working!